# How to speed up large JSON parse and select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, postgresql

I have a large JSON file with customer contacts, approximately 3.5MB size and ~26k entries. The objects included have only `:id, :name, :email, :account_id`. I am using Rails as a backend API and Angular in the front.

So, what I do when I want to display a form with a select box including the customer objects with `:account_id` equal to what I want, is query Rails.

```
def get_account_contacts
   if params[:account_id].present?
      @contacts = JSON.parse(File.read('data/contacts.json'))
      @account_id = params[:account_id]
      @contacts_by_account_id = @contacts.select {|k| k["account"] == @account_id}
      render json: @contacts_by_account_id
   end
end
```

The problem is that the query takes 8 to 13 seconds to complete, so it confuses the user that wants to select a value from the dropdown. I tried to add a spinner but 13 seconds are too much for this kind of query, so I am looking to find ways that I could decrease the load.

One thing I thought about was to save all JSON objects to a Postgres table, which will turn the entire entity ultra fast. The customer contacts JSON rarely gets large changes, so I am running a cron job daily to fetch the data and write them in a .json file.

Should I abandon all hope to make it faster as is, or must I follow the road of Postgres persisting ?

Comment: I would say abandon all hope to try to make a file-based database. Use *any* database instead. You could normalize you data and store it in any relational database, you could store `json(b)` documents with PostgreSQL, or you could use a NoSQL database too, any of these would be so much faster that a single flat file, which is read all the times a user asks for a record from it.

Comment: @pozs but instead of writing all data as text in a file, I will need to persist 25k rows at once to the db. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: no, that's not even considered a large DB. Relational DBs could store millions of rows.

Comment: @pozs obviously, but how about performance while storing 25k in a very short amount of time ?

Comment: Storing all that data one time should not be a problem either. F.ex. postgres has the [`copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) functionality. Other DB vendors might have their own way to address this, but even multiple inserts should run under a few seconds (considering only the really required indexes set up). And usually synchronizations run a significatly fewer times than reads.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing large json string. I suggest you use some high-performance JSON parser gem like [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj).

Answer (score 1):

Have you identified where your bottleneck is?

If not i recommend you call [binding.pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and run each line manually to see where it takes more time, for this you will need to run your server with rails server.

```
def get_account_contacts
   if params[:account_id].present?
      binding.pry
      @contacts = JSON.parse(File.read('data/contacts.json'))
      @account_id = params[:account_id]
      @contacts_by_account_id = @contacts.select {|k| k["account"] == @account_id}
      render json: @contacts_by_account_id
   end
end
```

> The customer contacts JSON rarely gets large changes, so I am running a cron job daily to fetch the data and write them in a .json file.

If you fetch it directly from a database maybe you would be better of by calling the query on that database directly(without the json file as a intermediary step), databases are designed exactly for this kind of job.

If you want to avoid to setup a postgresql database you can always use a sqlite3 database, for your purpose it may be enough.

Best Regards!.

Comment: I fetch them from a private external API which limits the results to 500, so I have to loop a job in order to retrieve them all, so I can either write them directly to a db or a file. The file gets easily setup and r/w because it's getting re-created before each write procedure, but the db is way faster. I just don't know which way is more sane and professional.

Comment: Since you are going to filter by the account_id field i think a database would be a better approach to your problem.

Comment: If you have a database engine running already use it, or try with sqlite3 if isn't fast enough move to postgres/mysql. If you go for sqlite you may find handy to use sqlitebrowser.